# C - why cant i read a linked list in a module and return the header in main?

Tags: c, linked-list

Today I was pretty confident I would get 100% on my exam, but I wasted all my time trying to fix this error, needless to say I never finished and I'm pretty fed up with it. The idea is:

```
typedef struct Poly{
    int x;
    int y
    struct Poly *next;
}Poly;

Poly *add_poly();

int main(){

Poly *a = (Poly*)malloc(sizeof(Poly));

a = add_poly(); //so this should be ret, the first 2 ints i typed should be here

printf("%dx^%d",a->x,a->y); //this works
a=a->next;
printf("%dx^%d",a->x,a->y); //this crashes.

}

Poly *add_poly(){
    Poly *temp = (Poly*)malloc(sizeof(Poly));
    Poly *ret = (Poly*)malloc(sizeof(Poly));

    temp = ret; //make sure i get to keep the header of the list?

    while(1){

        scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);

        temp->x=x;
        temp->y=y

        printf("%dx^%d",temp->x,temp->y);//authentication

        temp=temp->next;
        temp=(Poly*)malloc(sizeof(Poly));

        if(y==0){
            temp->x=0;
            temp->y=0;
            break;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

I don't get it! I've worked with linked lists before in much more complex coding but I never had this problem, I must be missing something but I wasted 1:30 hour trying to find the mistake in the exam, and another 2 hours after I went home, same error, even if I actualy deleted and retyped every command from scratch...

Comment: Nice rant. Now post an actual question.

Comment: You are writing about an error. Which error ??

Comment: printf("%dx^%d",a->x,a->y); //this works
a=a->next;
printf("%dx^%d",a->x,a->y); //this crashes why?

Comment: Errors like: it leaks and it bleeds and nothing is returned or printed?

Comment: @joop. I hope the blood at least gets returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only allocate a node if you need one. Allocate the node where `next` points to, before you step one forward.

```
Poly *add_poly(){

    Poly *ret = (Poly*)malloc(sizeof(Poly)); // allocate first node
    ret->next = NULL;                        // successor of first node is NULL

    Poly *temp = ret;
    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%d %d", &temp->x, &temp->y);  // read data
        printf("%dx^%d", temp->x, temp->y);  // print data

        if ( temp->y==0 )                    // terminate if y == 0
            break;

        temp->next = (Poly*)malloc(sizeof(Poly)); // allocate next node right to target
        temp = temp->next;                        // step one forward
        temp->next = NULL;                        // successor of last node is NULL
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Don't allocate memory if you don't need it. `a` is set by the return value of function `add_poly`. If you allocte memory to `a` in `main`, this becomes a memory leak. Apart from this don't forget to `free` your memory at end of program.

```
int testmain(){

    Poly *a = add_poly();   // read data and create list

    Poly *temp = a
    while ( temp != NULL )  // print data from list
    {
        printf("%dx^%d",temp->x,temp->y);
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    while ( a != NULL )     // free list
    {
        temp = a->next;
        free( a );
        a = temp;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it works! thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your objects that you allocate on the heap. The next pointer in your objects is never set to NULL.

You also have several memory leaks, here what `a` originally points to is leaked:

```
Poly *a = (Poly*)malloc(sizeof(Poly));
a = add_poly();
```

and here what temp originally points to is leaked:

```
  Poly *temp = (Poly*)malloc(sizeof(Poly));
  Poly *ret = (Poly*)malloc(sizeof(Poly));
  temp = ret;
```

here you put in x and y in the temp node

```
    temp->x=x;
    temp->y=y
```

but here you take the uninitialized next pointer and assign it to temp so it ends with a memory leak and temp pointing somewhere in the blue

```
    temp=temp->next;
```

When you declare a pointer you do not need to allocate it in some way which it seems you do.

Only when you want to add a node should you allocate and make sure the contents of the node are initialized properly:

e.g. `memset(ptr, 0, sizeof(Poly));`

So something like this (you should check return values of sscanf etc in real code), let's assume you have two pointers one first and one last:

```
Poly* first = NULL;
Poly* last = NULL;

char values[100];
while (fgets(values, sizeof(values), stdin) != NULL)
{
  sscanf(values,"%d %d", &x, &y);

  node = malloc(sizeof(Poly));
  node->x = x;
  node->y = y;
  node->next = NULL;

  if (last == NULL)
  {
    first = last = node;
  }
  else
  {
    last->next = node;
    last = node;
  }
}
```

Comment: temp = temp->next matters if temp->next is not set to NULL? i'm still a rookie and in university we are not learning how to avoid leaks. what if I use a:    Poly *empty = (Poly*)malloc(sizeof(poly)); and empty->x=0;empty->y=0;empty->next=NULL; ?

Comment: @Panagiotis not sure why you call it empty, you are about create a node to store your values in the linked list. but yes, that is how you would initialize a new node

Answer (score 0):

The program has numerous memory leaks.

It can look the following way

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Poly
{
    int x;
    int y;
    struct Poly *next;
} Poly;

Poly * add_poly( Poly *head );

int main( void )
{
    Poly *head = NULL;
    Poly *next = NULL;

    head = add_poly( head ); //so this should be ret, the first 2 ints i typed should be here

    printf( "%d %d\n", head->x, head->y ); //this works

    next = head->next;

    printf( "%d %d\n", next->x, next->y ); //this crashes.
}

Poly * add_poly( Poly *head )
{
    Poly **current = &head;
    int x, y;

    while( *current ) current = &( *current )->next;

    do
    {
        if ( scanf( "%d %d", &x, &y ) != 2 || x == 0 )
        {
            x = 0; y =0;
        }

        *current = malloc( sizeof( Poly ) ); 

        ( *current )->x = x;
        ( *current )->y = y;


        current = &( *current )->next;
    } while ( x != 0 );


    return head;
}
```

Comment: while( *head ) head = &( *head )->next; i don't know what this means at all, also ( *current )->x = x; is this equal to current->x=x? @Vlad

Comment: @Panagiotis There were typos. Try the program now.

Comment: `Poly * add_poly( Poly *head )` -->> `void add_poly( Poly **current)` and remove the declaration for current in the function.

Comment: @joop It is an invalid advice. The code now is compiled